# Selenium is launching dummy browser along with the browser to run automation

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

Can anyone please clarify my query? My chrome browser recently got updated to the latest version 87.0.4280.88.
Once its got updated, "WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();" is launching two browser instances.
One browser seems empty, with "data:," as a URL.
In another browser, selenium is running.
Can anyone please help us to resolve this issue by stopping another empty browser from launching?
I hereby added the screenshots for reference.

[image: Source code]

[image: Output]

Comment: I also updated the chromedriver.exe to match the chrome browser version but still facing this issue.

Comment: Can you pull out the _chromedriver.exe_ from `java\\com` directory and place it somewhere else and change the path accordingly and retest?

Comment: Yes still the same.